# how to categorize solutions

Tags: trailhead, superbadges, solutions

i am solving https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge-lex-rd

this superbadge for this i need to create solution

and store that solution in category i have created solution but i canot see where i can assign category to that solution

can anyone help to categorizing the solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're in Salesforce Classic (Solutions are not available in Lightning Experience). Next, configure your categories in Setup > Customize > Solutions > Solution Categories. After that, check your page layout in Setup > Customize > Solutions > Page Layouts, edit the layout, go to the Related List section in the layout palette, and add Solution Categories to the page (choose Yes to apply changes to all users). Finally, you can go back to the Solution you created, and you can add the categories you want.